# three js: how to mix two scenes (one with bloom)

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I have one Renderer object and two scene objects. One scene contains the objects that should not be processed by the unrealbloom post-processing pass and the other scene contains all “glowing” objects.

Now I thought I could do:

```
const THREED_Composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( THREED_Renderer );
const THREED_RenderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( THREED_Scene, THREED_Camera );
const THREED_RenderPassGlow = new THREE.RenderPass( 
    THREED_SceneGlow, THREED_Camera );
const THREED_BloomPass = new THREE.UnrealBloomPass(
    new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), 0.5, 0.5, 0.4);
//THREED_BloomPass.renderToScreen = false; ???
THREED_Composer.addPass( THREED_RenderPassGlow );
THREED_Composer.addPass( THREED_BloomPass );
THREED_Composer.addPass( THREED_RenderPass );
```

The intention was to first render the glowing objects and then render the non-glowing objects over them. I want the non-glowing objects to be able to obscure the glowing objects.

My animate function looks like this:

```
function animate()
{
    if(GLOBAL_FocusLost)
        return;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    update();
    THREED_Composer.render();
}
```

Ultimate goal:
I want to have glowing monolith in the midst of a room that can be obscured by all other objects.

I tried to read my way through the documentation but I think that I do not understand it enough.

Cheers. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the example with selective bloom: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=bloom#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom_selective

Comment: I did, but I do not understand it.